# Write detected result to text file

Tags: batch-file, text, output, detection

I have a simple `.bat` program that reads the name of the IC on the board. The program works fine and it reads the IC properly. In a return it writes the name of the IC like the image shows below:

[image]

But it does not write the name MINI52ZDE anywhere (exit code for example), so I could know what type of a IC it is.

I would like to have the exit code MINI52ZDE or write the detection to a .txt file so i can run another program depending on the detection of IC (I have 2 diffrent types).

This is the code i used for that .bat file:

```
NuLink –r UID > tip.txt
NuLink -p

:finish
pause
```

Without the quotes :). The tip.txt file is used to write the the name, but im always getting a command error written in the tip.txt file.

Any have any solution to this?

Best

Comment: your link  : http://i65.tinypic.com/2i06pzl.png is dead

Comment: The link works fine, try it in a different browser.

Comment: Don't work for me ! With FF and with Cr

Comment: Here are some more links:
http://imgur.com/aADvk65
https://i.imgsafe.org/1e0aa22.png
http://postimg.org/image/qn7u3f1dn/

Comment: Using an image here was totally unnecessary. You can simply copy the text output of the command window and paste it in as text, with much less effort than it takes to create the image. Images should only be used when there is absolutely no other way to demonstrate the issue you're having. They're hard to read on mobile devices, many company proxy servers block the image servers (meaning the content isn't available to readers) and you can't copy/paste content from images. Please remember that when posting in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
NuLink –r UID
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('NuLink -p') do set "$ID=%%a"

:finish
echo %$ID%
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but didn't work on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I have manage to get it to write inot the text file, it was a very simple solution actually. Here is the code:

```
@echo 

NuLink –r UID
NuLink -p c:\>UID.txt

:finish
exit
```

Thank you everyone for the help! But im still open to any solutions if anyone have :)!

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%a in ('NuLink -p') do set "$ID=%%b"
```